# OBSOLETE - Unanswered questions with tags returns wrong total

Tags: bug, obsolete

When requesting a list of unanswered questions with a specific tags the total count show the total number of questions for that tag, not the count for the unanswered questions.

Using http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions/unanswered?tagged=iphone I get, at the time of writing the following response:

```
{
  "total": 52312,
```

I expect to get

```
{
  "total": 13628,
```

Which is what stackoverflow.com displays when viewing unanswered questions tagged `iphone`.

52312 is the total number of questions tagged with `iphone`.

When using the query without the `tagged` parameter the response is correct.

*The numbers are, of course, the actual values when I performed the query*